# Mongodb Query Doesn't Use Index

Tags: mongodb

I have a compound index set up on a mongo collection, and no matter how specifically I target the prefix, I can't get the query to use it.

How index was created:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"insert_time":-1,"name":"text"},{background: true})
```

Index specification output:

```
db.collection.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "db.collection"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "insert_time" : -1,
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "insert_time_-1_name_text",
    "ns" : "db.collection",
    "background" : true,
    "weights" : {
        "name" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
]
```

But when I run even the simplest query on insert_time, `explain()` shows me that the winning plan is to do COLLSCAN, and not use any index:

```
db.collection.find({"insert_time": ISODate("2018-08- 
05T19:00:00Z")}).explain()
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "db.collection",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "insert_time" : {
            "$eq" : ISODate("2018-08-05T19:00:00Z")
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "filter" : {
            "insert_time" : {
                "$eq" : ISODate("2018-08-05T19:00:00Z")
            }
        },
        "direction" : "forward"
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "foo",
    "port" : 0000,
    "version" : "3.4.10",
    "gitVersion" : "078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9"
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Even though the index is specified as a "compound index", my understanding is that I should be able to search by a "prefix", which in this case, `insert_time` is.  Any ideas as to why mongo won't use my index?

Answer (score 5):

`text` index is [sparse by default](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#indexes-that-are-sparse-by-default).

And non-text index field in index does not reference document in `text` index ([reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-compound-indexes))

> For a compound index that includes a text index key along with keys of other types, only the text index field determines whether the index references a document. The other keys do not determine whether the index references the documents or not.

=> When use prefix index with out text index field, the result may incomplete

About this case ([sparse Index and Incomplete Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-index-and-incomplete-results)), MongoDB states that:

> If a sparse index would result in an incomplete result set for queries and sort operations, MongoDB will not use that index unless a hint() explicitly specifies the index.

If you use `hint('yourTextIndexName')` then the index is used.

So OP's case is an expected behaviour, but is not very well documented.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Question also seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893232/mongodb-query-does-not-use-prefix-on-compound-index-with-text-field/44894103#44894103

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a bug.

I'm able to reproduce the behavior you're seeing on my own dataset, with MongoDB 3.6.7. I hinted the index in question and the query planner was unable to bound on the prefix field (I was doing a direct match on `year`):

```
"indexBounds" : {
                    "year" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "_fts" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "_ftsx" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
```

The documentation for [compound text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#compound-index) does not contain any statements indicating it is not possible to use the prefix portion of a text index. The documentation on [index prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) also do not contain any language regarding a restriction.

EDIT:

I created a [server ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37059) to report this behavior and try to get more information on if this is expected or a bug.

Comment: There is indeed not much explanation on how compound text indexes work, but my hunch is that it is still one index entry per text token. This would mean that you cannot do a query on just `insert_time` because that would fail to find the documents where the text field is completely empty. The prefix columns would only be useful to efficiently limit on top of a text search.

Comment: Maybe adding something like `AND text HAS ANY TOKENS` would make it work? But I have no idea how to write that.

Comment: I am also getting the feeling that text indexes can only be used to perform a text search. I would have expected this to be documented under compound text indexes though. Also, this statement seems almost (but does not) suggests that they can be used for non-text search: `
If the compound text index includes keys preceding the text index key, to perform a $text search, the query predicate must include equality match conditions on the preceding keys.` (from compound text index link above).

Comment: See my edit; I created a server ticket to try to get confirmation on if this is expected.

Comment: Please cross-link that ticket back to here.

Comment: The ticket I created was https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37059 but I think Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn found some documentation to confirm this is expected behavior.